# Lubuntu and not Ubuntu: how to add a network printer?

Tags: lubuntu, printing

Under Preferences, Printers, Add, Network Printer, Find Network Printer why can't this operating system do so?
What is a HOST?

Comment: Start with the basics. Is the printer turned on? Is the printer on the correct network? Is it really a network printer?

Comment: **Welcome to the Ask Ubuntu community.** As @user535733 noted, your question is unclear. Please edit your question to include the printer make/model so that we can help you troubleshoot your issue. Thanks

Comment: I consider my Lubuntu system a Ubuntu system; as Lubuntu is just a different set of packages on top of the standard Ubuntu base by design (*it's an official flavor, built on Ubuntu infrastructure from a different [seed](https://people.canonical.com/~ubuntu-archive/seeds/lubuntu.lunar/desktop) file to Ubuntu Desktop*).  Key detail is what release are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Access the CUPS (Common Unix Printing Sysyem) GUI by pointing your browser  to `http://localhost:631`.

You can detect, add, and manage printers from the `Admin` tab, and deal with individual printers from the `Printers` tab. You can set the system default printer.

From the command line,

`lpstat -t`

will show the total state of the printing system.